# Better practice: Multiple objects into an array or separate threads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, multiple-instances

I am working on a really, really simple rendition of the [parachute shooter game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parachute_%28iPod_game%29), all in javascript.I am pretty new to javascript, with a background in java and OOP. Maybe I'm completely wrong here and maybe I just don't have any understanding of how javascript works, but the way I see it, I have two options to track the falling parachuters.

I can either create multiple parachuter objects and store them in some array of size `n`, however many can exist on the game field at one time **or**  I can somehow create multiple threads of the parachuter object within the game board that will act independently of each other and only interact with the rockets being fired at them.

I'm not very familiar with the second option and don't really know how that would be achieved. I'm open to any pointers and different ideas for how to handle all of the parachuters. Which of those two is more efficient and manageable? Are both of them feasible? I don't necessarily want someone to give me their code for those (though it would be helpful), I just want to talk about theory and method.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: javascript always executes in a single thread(except workers)

Comment: so is it best to create, store, and track multiple objects in an array?

Comment: javascript runs in a single thread, evented loop. so, yes, multiple object instances in an array / parent object is the way to go.

Comment: As the others mentioned, JavaScript is, generally, single-threaded. Regardless, when doing gaming programming, you're better off writing a standard game loop. My suggestion would be to keep track of the multiple objects, either in an array or some other composite object, and implement a standard game loop. Google "game loop design" for some ideas. Also, this question is better suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarcBaumbach Thanks, keep that in mind for future questions.